# Seeking after notation for two objects equal up to a constant

Tags: soft-question, notation

Sometimes we want to express that two objects are equal up to a constant but there is no need to keep writing out the constant or constants. For example, often times the constant or constants involved in the derivation of a primitive of a function plays or play a role unimportant.

I wonder if there is a convenient, established notation for such a matter. I thought of using modular notation. But using that does not simplify because I still have to mention "modulo-what".

If possible, some variants of the equality sign are preferable. For instance, if the constant of proportionality is unimportant then it may be suppressed by using $\propto.$ In this sense I mean by saying that some variants of the equality sign are preferable.

Comment: well you could also try with Landau notation.

Comment: @timmbob: Thanks. I would prefer some variants of the equality sign.

Comment: People usually write $A=B+O(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no standard notation.  I have seen $\propto$ used in the additive context as well as the multiplicative, leaving it to the reader to overcome the abuse of notation.

Answer (score 1):

> two objects are equal up to a constant

The answer might depend on what the objects are, and what operation is applied to the object and the constant.

But [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) could be a good fit.  To quote wikipedia:

> $37$ and $57$ are congruent modulo $10$,
>
> $ 37 \equiv 57 \pmod {10} $
>
> since $37 − 57 = − 20$ is a multiple of $10$

If you explicitly define your notation and stay consistent, then it is fine to just use the $\equiv$ symbol without the$\pmod n$.

There are other kinds of congruence with different notation.  But, as above, congruence in abstract algebra is usually denoted as a triple-struck equals sign $\equiv$.

Comment: This doesn't work in general.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Equivalence relation is too general for what OP wants, congruence relation (mod n), although restricted, is only defined on certain groups: Integers, fractions, polynomials, etc. If you are using congruence relation as an abstract algebra term, then you are talking about some particular relation on some set, not **about** two elements in a set which OP wants.

Comment: For example, saying $a$ is congruent to $b$ doesn't say much because you have to specify given what relation are the two congruent. Doable, but tedious and much more complicated than just saying equal up to a constant.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details.  To clarify, I only meant to point vaguely in the direction of congruence, the triple-struck equals sign, and their various uses.  Without more detail on OP’s specific context, it’s difficult to make specific suggestions, so I didn’t intend to.  Is there a particular part of my answer you’d suggest revising or removing?

Comment: You are welcome, and no, I don't think your answer is "wrong," or that it needs revision that's why I didn't downvote it. I just added the caveat. No need to add or remove anything.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In many fields, such as applied statistics, machine learning, and signal processing, the equality of two quantities $X, Y$ up to an additive constant is often denoted by $X\overset{c}{=}Y$. This notation is quite natural both in its modification of the ordinary equals sign $=$ and in its consistency with the common practice of writing $X = Y + c$ elsewhere in math, science, and engineering. However, it is currently far from standard and should be defined upon its first usage in every document.

Here are a few well-cited works that make use of this notation:

- [Leglaive, Girin, and Horaud (2019)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8683704)
- [Sykulski, Olhede, Lilly, and Early (2017)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7884990)
- [Maltiel, Raftery, McCormick, and Baraff (2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4777323/)
- [Liutkus, Fitzgerald, Badeau (2015)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7336900)
- [Chang, Wei, and Fisher III (2013)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6619111)
- [Wilson, Knowles, and Ghahramani (2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4411)

Answer (score -2):

As $∝$ looks like c and × together, A similar symbol could look like c and + together:$\Subset\hspace{-0.78em}\color{white}{\subset}\hspace{-0.4em}\large\shortmid$